# how to show the image under $T$ of the unit ball in $L^p[0,1]$ has compact closure in $C[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis

let $K:[0,1]\times [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and let $1<p<\infty$. For $f\in L^p[0,1]$, let $Tf$ be the function on $[0,1]$ defined by $$(Tf)(x)=\int_0^1K(x,y)f(y)dy$$
How to show  the image under $T$ of the unit ball in $L^p[0,1]$ has compact closure in $C[0,1]$.

I only know that $Tf$ is continuous. The unit ball in $L^p[0,1]$ is closed or not? How is the image under $T$ of the unit ball in $L^p[0,1]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: the [Arzela-Ascoli theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem) is usually the best tool for dealing with compactness in a space $C(X)$.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot.By your suggestion, I have worked it out.